# Css media queries percent width

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have following markup (simplified for demostration)

https://jsfiddle.net/n07znakb/3/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="playlist-inner">
    <div class="playlist-content">

      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>
      <div class="playlist-item"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

playlist-content is the width of 1000px (which is playlist-item number x  playlist-item width), I set this in javascript.

If there were 10 playlist-items then the width would be 2000px for example.

I want to achieve the following:

wrapper max width is 600px, 3 playlist-items are visible (this works)
when the wrapper width is between 600 and 400px, I want playlist items to be 33.3% width of the playlist-inner (which is the second upper parent!), so 3 playlist items visible.
when the wrapper width is below 400px width, I want playlist items to be 50% width of the playlist-inner (which is the second upper parent!), so 2 playlist items visible.

I know I can do this with javascript. I wonder if I can do it with css alone?

With current css it doesnt work because setting 33.3% width takes parent width which is playlist-content, but I want it to be 33.3% width of one more upper parent which is playlist-inner.

Hopefully someone will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should code from mobile and up.
And set the wrapper to be relative.

So from 0px to be drastic, you want the playlist items to be 100%;

```
.playlist-item{width:100%;}
```

from 400 and up, you want 50%;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
   .playlist-item{width:50%;}
}
```

from 600 and up, you want 33.3%;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .playlist-item{width:33.3%;}
}
```

I made a ul list for example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n07znakb/4/

Comment: But this doesnt follow my example, I have items in parent in single line then followed by anther parent which width is restricted. I would like to size my items on that upper parent.

Comment: @ Toniq I dont think you can size the childs from another parent unless you do a javascript solution. Why do you need the inner parent? It doesn work like that. Just make sure the parent to your items has a width and is set to position:relative, the childs should follow that parent only. If you need the inner parent, you might get away with position absolute on that one ,to make your kids follow the closest relative parent, but I'm not sure. What you try to do doesnt follow the standards as I can see it. Can you explain why you need it in excatly that way? Maybe you can rewrite it.